# Why does list.append() return None?

Tags: python

I am trying to calculate a postfix expression using Python, but it did not work. I think this is maybe a Python-related problem.

Any suggestions?

```
expression = [12, 23, 3, '*', '+', 4, '-', 86, 2, '/', '+']

def add(a,b):
    return a + b
def multi(a,b):
    return a* b
def sub(a,b):
    return a - b
def div(a,b):
    return a/ b


def calc(opt,x,y):
    calculation  = {'+':lambda:add(x,y),
                     '*':lambda:multi(x,y),
                     '-':lambda:sub(x,y),
                     '/':lambda:div(x,y)}
    return calculation[opt]()



def eval_postfix(expression):
    a_list = []
    for one in expression:
        if type(one)==int:
            a_list.append(one)
        else:
            y=a_list.pop()
            x= a_list.pop()
            r = calc(one,x,y)
            a_list = a_list.append(r)
    return content

print eval_postfix(expression)
```

Comment: Totally unrelated to your question but 1/ you may want to read the doc for the `operator` module, and 2/ in your `calc` function you don't need lambdas at all - just map to the operator functions and pass arguments at call time, ie : `{"+": add, "-":sub,}[opt](x, y)`. This will also allow you to define the mapping globally hence avoiding building it again and again on each call to `calc`.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers ,thanks, that`s wondeful!!!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just replace `a_list = a_list.append(r)` with `a_list.append(r)`.

**Most** functions, methods that change the items of sequence/mapping does return `None`: `list.sort`, `list.append`, `dict.clear` ...

Not directly related, but see [Why doesn’t list.sort() return the sorted list?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-doesn-t-list-sort-return-the-sorted-list).

Comment: I disagree with `sorted`. It returns the sorted list.

Comment: Your link to the FAQ about the `list.sort()` method is very relevant. We can easily understand why append does not return a new list but directly modify the argument. (+1)

Answer (score 17):

The method `append` does not return anything:

```
>>> l=[]
>>> print l.append(2)
None
```

You must not write:

```
l = l.append(2)
```

But simply:

```
l.append(2)
```

In your example, replace:

```
a_list = a_list.append(r)
```

to

```
a_list.append(r)
```

Comment: thank you very much for your quick answer and related discussion.there is only one gree V I can click,,,

Answer (score 6):

For return data on append use:

```
b = []   
a = b.__add__(['your_data_here'])
```

Comment: That's nice  - and i just replace `.append` with .__add__` in my code. It's a PITA that these `list` methods are not chainable.   What would be the analogous equivalent of `.extend` ?

Answer (score 1):

`append` function mutates the list and it returns None. This is the piece of code which does that http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/aa3a7d5e0478/Objects/listobject.c#l791

```
listappend(PyListObject *self, PyObject *v)
{
    if (app1(self, v) == 0)
        Py_RETURN_NONE;
    return NULL;
}
```

So, when you say

```
a_list = a_list.append(r)
```

you are actually assigning `a_list` with `None`. So, the next time when you refer to `a_list`, it is not pointing to the list but the `None`. So, as others have suggested, change

```
a_list = a_list.append(r)
```

to

```
a_list.append(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions like list.append(),list.sort() don't return anything.
e.g

```
def list_append(p):
    p+=[4]
```

function list_append doesn't have an return statement.so when you run following statements:

```
a=[1,2,3]
a=list_append(a)
print a
>>>None
```

but when you run following statements:

```
a=[1,2,3]
list_append(a)
print a
>>>[1,2,3,4]
```

That's it.so,hoping it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

List methods can be divided in two types those who mutate the lists in place and return `None` (literally) and those who leave lists intact and return some value related to the list.

First category:

```
append
extend
insert
remove
sort
reverse
```

Second category:

```
count
index
```

The following example explains the differences.

```
lstb=list('Albert')
lstc=list('Einstein')

lstd=lstb+lstc
lstb.extend(lstc)
# Now lstd and lstb are same
print(lstd)
print(lstb)

lstd.insert(6,'|')
# These list-methods modify the lists in place. But the returned
# value is None if successful except for methods like count, pop.
print(lstd)
lstd.remove('|')
print(lstd)

# The following return the None value
lstf=lstd.insert(6,'|')
# Here lstf is not a list.
# Such assignment is incorrect in practice.
# Instead use lstd itself which is what you want.
print(lstf)

lstb.reverse()
print(lstb)

lstb.sort()
print(lstb)

c=lstb.count('n')
print(c)

i=lstb.index('r')
print(i)
```

pop method does both. It mutates the list as well as return a value.

```
popped_up=lstc.pop()
print(popped_up)
print(lstc)
```

Answer (score 0):

just a thought, instead of those functions (which manipulates the actual data) returning None, they should have returned nothing.
Then atleast the user would have caught the issue as it would have throwed an error stating some assignment error!!
Comment your thoughts!!

Comment: In Python "returning nothing" means returning `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody ends here, I encountered this behavior while trying to append on a return call

This works as expected

```
def fun():
  li = list(np.random.randint(0,101,4))
  li.append("string")
  return li
```

This returns `None`

```
def fun():
  li = list(np.random.randint(0,101,4))
  return li.append("string")
```