# Obscurity in "lambda" function in python

Tags: python, list, lambda

I want to make a model of "walking" over a gird.

[image]

so I created 8 functions:

```
g0 = lambda ct: ct.append((lambda (x,y): (x-1,y))(ct[-1]))
g1 = lambda ct: ct.append((lambda (x,y): (x-1,y+1))(ct[-1]))
g2 = lambda ct: ct.append((lambda (x,y): (x,y+1))(ct[-1]))
g3 = lambda ct: ct.append((lambda (x,y): (x+1,y+1))(ct[-1]))
g4 = lambda ct: ct.append((lambda (x,y): (x+1,y))(ct[-1]))
g5 = lambda ct: ct.append((lambda (x,y): (x+1,y-1))(ct[-1]))
g6 = lambda ct: ct.append((lambda (x,y): (x,y-1))(ct[-1]))
g7 = lambda ct: ct.append((lambda (x,y): (x-1,y-1))(ct[-1]))
```

but when I try to apply any function I get `None`:

```
print g0([(50,50)])
None
```

well, Iet's try more traditional way:

```
def g0(ct):
    ct.append((lambda (x,y): (x-1,y))(ct[-1]))
    return ct
```

that's works as expected:

```
[(50, 50), (49, 50)]
```

But when I try

```
def g0(ct):          
    return ct.append((lambda (x,y): (x-1,y))(ct[-1]))
```

the result is also `None`, Why?

Comment: `list.append()` always returns `None`, because the list is altered in-place instead. *Should* the list be altered in-place or do you want a new list object returned, leaving `ct` unaltered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`list.append()` alters the list in-place, and like all Python standard library methods that operate directly on the underlying mutable object, the method returns `None` to signal this.

Your `lambda` returns not the list object, but the result of `ct.append()`; e.g. `None`. You have two options:

- don't alter the original list, but return a new list instead:

  ```
  g0 = lambda ct: ct + [(lambda (x,y): (x-1,y))(ct[-1])]
  ```
- append to the original list and chain the original list object with `or` to return it instead of `None`:

  ```
  g0 = lambda ct: ct.append((lambda (x,y): (x-1,y))(ct[-1])) or ct
  ```

Demo:

```
>>> ct = [(50,50)]
>>> g0 = lambda ct: ct + [(lambda (x,y): (x-1,y))(ct[-1])]
>>> g0(ct)
[(50, 50), (49, 50)]
>>> ct
[(50, 50)]
>>> g0 = lambda ct: ct.append((lambda (x,y): (x-1,y))(ct[-1])) or ct
>>> g0(ct)
[(50, 50), (49, 50)]
>>> ct
[(50, 50), (49, 50)]
```

The first version leaves the original list unaffected; a new list object is returned. The second approach altered the original list; the return value and `ct` both refer to the same object.

Comment: Well structured answer (+1). We apparently thought about the same solution to return the list. Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 7):

Your lambda function appends an element to a list and it returns nothing (`None`):

```
g0 = lambda ct: ct.append((lambda (x,y): (x-1,y))(ct[-1]))
```

More precisely, it returns nothing because `ct.append(...)` is a method that returns `None` and your lambda returns what `ct.append(...)` returns.

In your second example, you are actually returning the list, so it works as you expect:

```
def g0(ct):
   ct.append((lambda (x,y): (x-1,y))(ct[-1]))
   return ct
```

However, be careful because even if you don't return the list, your list is actually altered.

You are also asking if it's possible to rewrite the lambda function to return the list... Well, yes but do not mention my name if someone asks you anything about this:

```
>>> g0 = lambda ct: (ct.append((lambda (x,y): (x-1,y))(ct[-1])) or ct)
>>> print g0([(50,50)])
[(50, 50), (49, 50)]
```

The code is not easy to read and I would suggest you to use functions instead.

Also, this question is related to your question: [why the list.append return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20016802/why-the-list-append-return-none)

Answer (score 3):

When you append an element to a list you return `None` as default, this leads to your expressions returning `None`.

In your 2nd example you append a `lambda` function to your list and *then return the list*. Which is why it works as you expect it should.

Comment: And, Is it possible to rewrite this `lambda` function to return list?

Comment: @shellenberg: I've been asking what you want to happen; does `ct` need to be altered in-place, or is it okay to return a *new* list?

Comment: Yes, I want to return a new list.