# Modifying a list value of a key in a dictionary directly

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Why can I not directly modify the list value in the following dict?

```
price_to_names = {'$': [], '$$': []}
price_to_names['$'] = price_to_names['$'].append('hello')
```

The following code changes the dict to

```
{'$': None, '$$': []}
```

I would like price_to_names to become

```
{'$': ['hello'], '$$': []}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-return-none-in-this-code, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20016802/why-the-list-append-return-none?

Answer (score 1):

`append` does not return a new list, if modifies the list in place.

`price_to_names['$'].append('hello')` is `None` because the `append` method of a list returns `None`. This is why you are assigning `None` as the value for the key `'$'`. Don't use an assignment, just append to your list:

```
>>> price_to_names = {'$': [], '$$': []}
>>> price_to_names['$'].append('hello')
>>> price_to_names
{'$$': [], '$': ['hello']}
```