# Putting finditer() output into an array

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to find the index of all "TRN" in a string, which I've done, but then I want to put all the indexes into an array, which I can't seem to do.

```
    import re

    string = 'a string with TRN, then another TRN'

    for match in re.finditer('TRN', string):
        spots = match.start()
        print(spots)
```

Output is:

```
14  
32
```

The output i want is:
[14, 32]

I've tried putting it into array and append the output like this, but the result is NONE NONE.

```
    import re

    into_array = []

    string = 'a string with TRN, then another TRN'

    for match in re.finditer('TRN', string):
        spots = match.start()
        x = into_array.append(spots)
        print(x)
```

Output is:

```
None  
None
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does list.append() return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20016802/why-does-list-append-return-none)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing the output of `append` (which doesn't output anything, hence `None`), not `spots` like you want to.

```py
import re

into_array = []

string = 'a string with TRN, then another TRN'

for match in re.finditer('TRN', string):
    spots = match.start()
    into_array.append(spots)
print(into_array)
```

Comment: you're right, but printing `spots` doesn't put the output into an array.

Comment: `into_array.append(spots)` puts each spot into the array though

Comment: now i understand about your comment about outputting the `append` and coming up with `none`. Thanks

Comment: i guess i was looking for `[ ]` the brackets to be outputted as well. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: If you want that as an output, you can remove `print(spots)` from the for loop and just have `print(into_array)` at the end.

Comment: @MrHobbit _printing `spots` doesn’t put the output into an array._ Why would it...?

Comment: @Dominic D, `print(into_array)` resulted in `[14]` followed by `[14, 32]`. You got me half-way there. i just need to figure out to remove the first `[14]`.

Comment: If you unindent that line so it's outside the for loop, it will only print once after the for loop is complete.

Comment: @Dominic D, you're a genius. That did it. Thank you very much.