# list of dataframe append having issue

Tags: python, pandas, list

I am trying to create a list of dataframes.

I print my dataframe normally and it works fine.

```
    print(df)
```

however if I create a list to store my df, it does not seem to work coz it prints 'None' from listOfDataframe.

```
    # Create list of data frame using list
    listOfDataframe = []
    listOfDataframe = listOfDataframe.append(df)
    print(listOfDataframe)
```

whats happening and How do I fix it?

Comment: Instead of `listOfDataframe = listOfDataframe.append(df)` should just be `listOfDataframe.append(df)`

Comment: Also related [Why does list.append() return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20016802/15497888)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to reassign a list after appending something to it. It changes it automatically:

```py
# Create list of data frame using list
listOfDataframe = []
listOfDataframe.append(df)
print(listOfDataframe)
```

It is returning None simply because the append method returns None.

See Henry Ecker's comments.