# One-line cleaning/manipulation of a list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am new to Python.

Start with: `bins = [.05, .1, .2, 1.0, -.35, .07, .1]`.

How can I compress the following code into a single line in Python? It seems that it should be possible, but I get an error when I try it. Note: I do not want to define a multi-line function elsewhere and then apply it here - that is just hiding multiple lines of code under the hood.

```
bins_2 = [x for x in bins if x >= 0] # Retain only nonnegative reals.
bins_2.insert(0, 0.0) # Insert 0.0 to the beginning of the list
bins_2 = list(dict.fromkeys(bins_2)) # Dedup the list
bins_2.sort() # Sort bins into ascending order using the standard ordering of the integers
```

The output should be: `bins_2 = [0.0, 0.05, 0.07, 0.1, 0.2, 1.0]` .

It is not so much that I am opposed to having multiple lines of code (which can aid with clarity). However, I think that if I could figure out how to compress this code into a single line, then I would better understand what is happening with the related functions in the language in general. I also would like to be conscientious of run-time, so I would prefer to start with or append [0.0], read through bins and filter out negatives, deduplicate the list, and then sort it in the most-efficient order.

---

I think that the issue is related to the problem which underlies this question: [Why does list.append() return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20016802/why-does-list-append-return-none)

For the beginning, I tried: `bins_2 = [0.0].extend([x for x in bins if x >= 0])`.

I also tried:

```
bins_2 = (list(dict.fromkeys(bins.insert(0, 0.0)))).sort()
bins_2 = [x for x in bins_2 if x >= 0]
```

Both failed. I think that this is due to the fact that functions like `insert()` and `sort()` modify the list to which they are applied and therefore should not be saved to another (or the same-named) variable.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly you can do:

```py
x = sorted(set(v for v in bins if v >= 0) | {0.0})
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
[0.0, 0.05, 0.07, 0.1, 0.2, 1.0]
```

---

For lower versions of python not supporting the union operator:

```py
x = sorted(set(v for v in bins if v >= 0).union([0.0]))
print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `set` instead of dictionary to dedup. You can combine it with list comprehension for filtering and the sort the result:

```py
bins_2 = sorted(set([0.0] + [x for x in bins if x >= 0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use list concatenation `[] + []`:

```
result = sorted(list(dict.fromkeys([0.0] + [x for x in bins if x >= 0])))
```